# Kill the grub-error tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-block-request

Why do we need a grub-error tag?

It will not fit both [grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/grub) and [grub2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/grub2) at the same time and its a useless tag to follow.

Normally if someone is good at solving [grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/grub) and [grub2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/grub2) issues he will also know how to solve errors on those tags.

We don't have a **unity-error** tag, we have [unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/unity), we dont have **wireless-error**, we have [wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wireless).

Why [grub-error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/grub-error)? Should we kill it?

Comment: Can grub be the master synonym please? I don't think it was intended for grub2 to the master..

Answer (score 7):

Yup. You might as well merge [grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/grub) into [grub2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/grub2) at the same time. If people need to specify Grub v1, they can do that.

Comment: I can remember the discussion on chat and I was against a merge at that point. I have changed my mind meanwhile because it just makes sense.

Comment: it's sounds very logical... it's pointless to have grub, grub2 and grub-error.

Answer (score 1):

Things to consider when discussing this:

- [grub-error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/grub-error) is generally a more serious error - however, while that needs to be taken into consideration, its not really a *stopping* problem.
- Currently, for the moment I have it as a [synonym of grub.](https://askubuntu.com/tags/grub/synonyms) However, because I didn't merge the tags, we can easily change that to whatever we want, if we need to.

Comment: Rename grub2 to grub please.